# How to count two fields by using Select statement in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, select

Total records in table are 10.

```
Select count(ID) from table1 where col1 = 1 (Result is 8)
Select count(ID) from table1 where col1 = 0 (Result is 2)
```

So its a same table but count is based on different condition. How am i gonna get two results (counts) using one select statement?

Also Performance is a big concern here.

PS: I am using Stored procedure...

**EDIT:
I wanna clear the above query is just a part of a big SP logic (for me at least). Since i got these following answers, it gave another idea to achieve it in different way. My above question is a bit changed now.....Please help here? Its a same col (bool type) with true or false state.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CASE:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE col1 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count1,
    SUM(CASE col1 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count0
FROM table1
```

Comment: Agree with @KM.  How do i do it?

Comment: For this CASE approach, you'd have to use SUM.

Answer (score 1):

You should use subselects or UNIONS, I don't see the other way...